# How do I programmatically check whether an image (PNG, JPEG) is corrupted or unsupported in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to load image in imageview but for some image my app is crashing while i am trying to get bitmap from image path.

Here is my code:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String imagePath){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Log:

```
   Process: kgs.com.librarytest2, PID: 17587
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
   Ljavax/imageio/ImageIO;
   at it.lamba.utils.KImageCheck.analyzeImage(KImageCheck.kt:26)
   at it.lamba.utils.KImageCheck.getImageData(KImageCheck.kt:53)
   at com.kitegamesstudio.kgspicker.ui.PickerFragment.handleSelection(PickerFragment.kt:524)at com.kitegamesstudio.kgspicker.ui.PickerFragment$getPagerAdapter$selectionDe legate$1.onItemSelected(PickerFragment.kt:494) at com.kitegamesstudio.kgspicker.ui.PagerFragment$selectionDelegate$1.onItemS lected(PagerFragment.kt:35) at com.kitegamesstudio.kgspicker.ui.RecyclerViewAdapter$ImageItemVieHolder$bi d$$inlined$with$lambda$1.onClick(RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:125) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6392)
```

Comment: logcat please share us.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code (a `getBitmap()` method) is unrelated to your stack trace, which does not refer to this method.

You appear to be using [this library](https://github.com/lamba92/KImageCheck). It is designed for use with Java SE, on a desktop or a server. It is using `javax.imageio.ImageIO`, which is not part of the Android SDK. You will need to remove this library from your project.